# "static method" vs "object property method"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What is the difference in relation to performance between this:

**Version 1:**

```
export default class User {

  static getList(data) {
   ...
  }

  static getItem(data) {
   ...
  }

}
```

and this:

**Version 2:**

```
export default {

  getList(data) {
   ...
  },
  getItem(data) {
  }
  ...

}
```

Both are called directly:

```
import User from "./User";
User.getList(data); // by static method (version 1)
User.getList(data); // by object property method (version 2)
```

So where lies the difference?

- Does the static method ("version 1) is only created once while the other object ("version 2") is cloned (?) every time when it s called?
- Does the class has overhead where object does not?
- Other things ?

Comment: There’s no difference in those respects. If you’re making a class just to put static things on it – don’t. Classes are for actual types in JavaScript.

Comment: The difference is that v2 is not a class. Considering that static-only class is antipattern, this is likely the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are simply properties of the constructor function object. So the difference would be that in the first case you are creating a function object (the constructor) and in the second case you are creating a "plain" object. I.e. simplified:

```
var firstExample = Object.assign(function() {}, {
  getList() {},
  getItem() {},
});
var secondExample = Object.assign({}, {
  getList() {},
  getItem() {},
});
```

You should use what makes the intention of your code clear. If you are never going to actually instantiate `User` then you shouldn't use a class for that.

---

> Does the static method ("version 1) is only created once while the other object ("version 2") is cloned (?) every time when it s called?

No. In both cases the methods are only created once.

> Does the class has overhead where object does not?

Probably. Creating a "class" involves more steps than creating an object. That however won't have any real performance on your application.